# How to start the progress of a seekbar from anywhere not from the beginning

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to create an android application with video cutting facility. For that I need to create a seekbar and when user clicks on "start cutting" button, progress of that seekbar must start from that position. And the when user clicks on "stop cutting", seekbar must stop at that point and the duration in between start to end must show in a different color. Please help me..

I want it to look some thing like following image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will far too good to use a double thumb seekbar.Just try
https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

Comment: I hope this one will help me.
Thanks Abhilash... :)

Comment: It worked for me... :)
setSelectedMinValue() and setSelectedMaxValue() inside that class helped me for that.
Once agian thanks Abhilash.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SeekBar` is a subclass of the `ProgressBar` you can try `setProgress()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress(int) method to start the initial point of the `SeekBar`.

There is also a secondary progress displayable on a progress bar which is useful for displaying intermediate progress, such as the buffer level during a streaming playback progress bar.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setSecondaryProgress(int)

Please see if that can be used for your use case...

Comment: I did that, but when setProgress(int) is used, progress color will start from the beginning. I want to start the progess color from that point.

Comment: can you share the screen shot of what is happening and what do you want? That would help in understanding the problem...

Comment: Since I'm new to stackoverflow.com, I'm unable to post screenshots.. :(
I'm looking for something like this,
http://www.bestofandroid.com/images/mp-cutter-android-app_taad-_0.jpg

Comment: Both setProgress() and setSecondaryProgress() starting from the beginning. For example if i give setMax(100) and setProgress(25), seek thumb will be in 25, but the 0-25 portion will be selected. I want to start that selection from 25.